# Using Array of Defaults in VBA to Populate Excel WBS with Outline

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, multidimensional-array

I've got a **`WBS`** (Work Break Down Structure), with multiple rows (top-level of a group outline), and each top-level row is an activity. Directly under the activity are the roles involved.

Based on the value of the activity in the top level ("plan", for example), the cells in the level below are populated, according to their values in a related table on another sheet ("defaults" tab).

Currently, the rows under the activity (that correspond to roles) are doing an ugly index/match lookup, which multiplied by 25 roles, can grind the spreadsheet to a halt.

What I *think* will solve this issue is taking the Role Defaults table, putting it in a persistent array, and using the values in the array over and over, as the user puts in the top-level activities. I just can't figure out how to make the array persistent (so the VBA doesn't repopulate it ever time a user changes a cell). If the values in the Role Defaults table changes, I can handle that with a worksheet `OnChange`, so that's not an issue.

[image: WBS Expanded Activity Rows, to show Roles]

Row 3 "Activity 1" is what the Activity Rows look like with the group outline collapsed.

Rows 4-9 are what the Activity Rows look like with the group outline expanded, showing the underlying roles.

[image: Role Defaults]

For each of the roles, this is the table on another tab that's used to look up the value that should be in the corresponding Activity/Role cell on the **`WBS`** tab.

Comment: `I just can't figure out how to make the array persistent` - by declaring it at the module level as opposed to procedure level. Then again, you probably should fix the ugly lookup because I'm not sure it absolutely has to be ugly.

Comment: Thanks @GSerg. The big issue with the ugly lookup is that I've got to do the role default lookup, plus other calculations based on other criteria, which requires the activity #. My end goal would be to change the Worksheet_Change function to only refrencing the top activity row, and reuse the role default array to populate the roles, instead of the current INDEX/MATCH for every cell beneath the activity week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a proponent of using `Dictionary` objects whenever the need for lookups arise. In my solution below, I use nested dictionaries to return a combination of Top-Level and Activity. (Note: I tried to understand your business need as best as I could, but I'm sure I didn't nail it. I also assumed some knowledge of VBA above a beginner's level. If you have follow up questions, please ask and we'll try and help).

First, create a new module to hold the globally available `Dictionary`. This cannot be a `Worksheet` module. (In the VBE, go to Insert --> Module). At the very top of the module, before creating a subroutine, declare a publicly available `Dictionary`

```
Public oDictWbs As Object
```

We only want one instance of this dictionary, so I like to use a `Singleton` like pattern which returns a `Dictionary` if already created, and if not, create and return a new one. (Note: I factored out the routine that returns a new dictionary into `RefreshWBS` so that it can be used to create a new dictionary based on your business rules. So, for example, in  the Default worksheet `OnChange` event, you can call `RefreshWBS` [code reuse is always fun]).

```
Private Function GetWBS() As Object
    If Not oDictWbs Is Nothing Then
        Set GetWBS = oDictWbs
        Exit Function
    End If

    Set GetWBS = RefreshWBS()
End Function

Private Function RefreshWBS()
    Dim sDefault As Worksheet
    Dim rTopLevels As Range
    Dim rActivities As Range
    Dim rIterator As Range
    Dim rInnerIter As Range

    Set oDictWbs = Nothing
    'Both variables below establish the range that stores the fixed info (the default worksheet)
    'Instead of hard coding in the range, create your own logic based on your needs and rules
    Set sDefault = Sheets("Default")
    Set rTopLevels = sDefault.Range("B1:C1")
    Set rActivities = sDefault.Range("A3:A4")

    Set oDictWbs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each rIterator In rTopLevels
        If Not oDictWbs.exists(rIterator.Value) Then
            Set oDictWbs(rIterator.Value) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        End If

        For Each rInnerIter In rActivities
            If Not oDictWbs(rIterator.Value).exists(rInnerIter.Value) Then
                oDictWbs(rIterator.Value)(rInnerIter.Value) = sDefault.Cells(rInnerIter.Row, rIterator.Column)
            End If
        Next rInnerIter
    Next rIterator

    Set RefreshWBS = oDictWbs

End Function
```

Finally, we create a function that can be accessed from within the Worksheet itself, allowing the user to access information in the WBS Dictionary. You can enter into an Excel cell a function like `=GetWbsActivityTime(B1, A4)` presuming that cell B1 contains the top-level descriptor and A4 describes the activity. So long as that value is in the dictionary, it will return the value associated with it.

```
Function GetWbsActivityTime(sTopLevel As String, sActivity As String) As Variant
    Dim oDict As Object

    Set oDict = GetWBS()

    If Not oDict.exists(sTopLevel) Then
        GetWbsActivityTime = CVErr(xlErrRef)
        Exit Function
    End If

    If Not oDict(sTopLevel).exists(sActivity) Then
        GetWbsActivityTime = CVErr(xlErrRef)
        Exit Function
    End If

    GetWbsActivityTime = oDict(sTopLevel)(sActivity)
End Function
```

I know it's a lot to absorb, so review it and let me know of any questions or quirks with which I can help. Also, if I totally missed the point of the exercise, let me know and I'll see if we can salvage parts of the solution.

Comment: Thanks @user3561813. I've not used dictionaries, so I appreciate the opportunity. I feel some clarification might help: The "Role Defaults" sheet contains a 3 dimensional table of Roles (column A), Activities (Row 3), and their values (A3:O37). This is used as the lookup for the user-entered descriptor (ex . "Plan", "Wkshp", etc), and input in to the corresponding role on the WBS tab. I'm going to see if I can modify your code to work with my specific scenario.

Comment: I'm still scratching my head how you did it, but when I replace your Set rTopLevels = sDefault.Range("B1:C1"), and Set rActivities = sDefault.Range("A3:A4") with my default roles row head range, and first column range, it works! Can I assume that the nested dictionary functions like creating a 3D array, and the Function GetWbsActivityTime uses the toplevel (header) and activity (role) to get the intersection value?

Comment: @RobS That is precisely what it does. The rTopLevels are the first key lookups. (Plan, Wkshp, etc). Each of these has its own underlying dictionary with its own keys (Proj Manag., Proj Manag - Offshore, etc). When the users selects `Plan` for example from the main dictionary, function points to the subdictionary included with `Plan`. If the user points to `Proj Mana` as the second parameters, it jumps to the key field and returns the value. If you have anymore questions, feel free to ask.